# Converting a String to a Double in Swift (Xcode v 7.0.1)

Tags: xcode, string, swift, casting, double

I am having a surprisingly hard time converting a String to a Double in Swift. Just to give you an overview of what I'm doing, I am parsing an XML file and retrieving values from certain elements. The code looks like this,

```
var lat = ""
var lati = 0.0

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {

    if elementName == "lat" {
        self.lat = foundCharacters
        self.lati = (self.lat as NSString).doubleValue
    }

}
```

When I print `self.lat` the coordinates get outputted as a String "36.97736". But, when I print `self.lati` the Double 0.0 gets printed.

I've also tried

```
self.lat = foundCharacters
let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US")
if let decimalAsDoubleUnwrapped = formatter.numberFromString(self.lat)       {
    self.lati = decimalAsDoubleUnwrapped.doubleValue
}
```

and I get the same result as before.

FIXED: Turns out there were extra white space characters (spaces) being added to the front of "36.97736" and Swift was complaining that the string wasn't of Double format so it was returning nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift 2.0, you can use Double("String") which returns an optional. Here is how to use it in your code

```
    lat = foundCharacters //not mentioned in the function btw
    if let doubleFromlat = Double(lat) {
        lati = doubleFromlat
    } else { print("foundCharacters does not hold double") }
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried this and it keeps going to the `else` statement. I printed `lat` and `lat` has the coordinates as a String. I then printed `Double(lat)` and I got `nil` for `Double(lat)`.

Comment: what is foundCharacters? I think thats where lat looses its value when you assign it to foundCharacters. Try printing lat after that assignment

Comment: It's "36.97736" but with 4 spaces being printed right in front of it. Also a new line gets printed right above "    36.97736". I tried trimming the whitespace but that hasn't worked either.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
extension String  {

    var asDouble : Double? {
        if let d = Double(self) {
            return d
        }
        return nil
    }
}


let s = "21.5"    
s.asDouble
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I know what the problem is now. Swift is not recognizing "36.97736" as a Double and so `self.lati = (self.lat as NSString).doubleValue` is assigning `nil` to `self.lati`. Why would this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(:)?.doubleValue`. So, in context of the snippet you posted:

```
let foundCharacters = "12.345"
let lat = foundCharacters
var lati: Double

if let doubleFromlat = Double(lat) {
    let lati = NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(foundCharacters)?.doubleValue
 } else {
    print("foundCharacters does not hold double")
 }
```